# Check if any socket connections are waiting (python)

Tags: python, sockets, networking

I am trying to run a task in an infinite loop but I would like to reserve the opportunity of changing some parameters along the way, hence I thought of using sockets to get this data over to my code. Unfortunately reading from a file is likely to be too slow.

The problem is that in most cases there are no incoming connections and I do not want to block the code. The best thing I could come up with is *setblocking(False)* and a *try* block but I wonder if someone can do this in a more pythonic way.

Sorry if this is super trivial. I am new to networking.

A short example of the thing I would like:

```py
import socket
from time import sleep

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 62800 

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
server.setblocking(False)
server.bind((HOST, PORT))
server.listen()

a_parameter = 0.1
counter = 0

def task(a):
    sleep(a)

    global counter
    counter+=1
    print(counter)


while True:
    try:
        conn, addr = server.accept() # will throw an error if no connections are in the queue
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)  
            a_parameter = float(data.decode("utf-8"))
            print("New parameter:", a_parameter)
    except:
        pass

    task(a_parameter)
```

You can try it with this client:

```py
import socket
import sys

HOST = '127.0.0.1'  # The server's hostname or IP address
PORT = 62800        # The port used by the server

with socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as s:
    s.connect((HOST, PORT))
    s.sendall(bytes(sys.argv[1], 'utf-8'))
```

Comment: Just run the normal blocking loop in a separate thread. Or else use a select loop.

Comment: I tried select before, but I didn't see a way not to block the code execution with it. The thread idea was useful however. I feel like this is a less wasteful way to go about it. Thank you.

Comment: Well you need a separate thread either way, you can't interleave this stuff with something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I opted for a separate thread based on a comment from user207421 as it feels less wasteful than *try* and more simple than *asyncio*. I copy my code here in case anyone is interested in the future:

```py
from threading import Thread
import socket
from time import sleep

HOST = '127.0.0.1'
PORT = 62800 


a_parameter = 0.1
counter = 0

def socket_handler_thread_function(threadname):

    global a_parameter

    server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) 
    server.bind((HOST, PORT))
    server.listen()

    print('listening on', (HOST, PORT))

    while True:
        conn, addr = server.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            data = conn.recv(1024)  
            a_parameter = float(data.decode("utf-8"))
            print("New parameter:", a_parameter)


def task(a):
    sleep(a)

    global counter
    counter+=1
    print(counter)

# daemon mode terminates the thread when the main code is killed 
socket_handler_thread = Thread(
        target=socket_handler_thread_function, 
        args=(1, ), 
        daemon=True
    )
socket_handler_thread.start()

while True:
    task(a_parameter)
```